# How can i persist date and Time with JPA Hibernate in MySql database ?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I want to persist Date and Time with JPA in my MySql Database.

But my Problem is, that the date is correct, but not the time. The time is always 02:00:00

My Implementation in the Entity Class is following:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date date;
```

And this is how i set im my Action Class the Date:

```
actualFactory.setDate(new java.util.Date());
```

The result in the db for the date colum for today is :

```
2015-09-30 02:00:00
```

Comment: and the type of the column created in the datastore is? and the SQL INSERT statement invoked (with parameter values) is?

Comment: the column in the database is : "datetime"

Comment: the colum in the db is: "datetime" and the insert Statement ist the following : insert 
    into
        Factory
        (atpMax, atpMin, createdBy, cycle, date, factoryName, inventarnumber, isActive, location, manufacturer, nitritMax, nitritMin, phMax, phMin, fk_product, fk_project, refraktionMax, refraktionMin, titrationMax, titrationMin, volume) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: add that to the question, and include the values of the parameters for the statement (some option in the logging)